# ¿Como puedo recibir y enviar datos a mi ajax desde un web service c#?

Tags: c#, ajax, webservice

Buenas a todos, estoy recibiendo error 500 cuando ejecuto mi llamada ajax hacia un web service, no entiendo muy bien el problema pero supongo que es por que estoy recibiendo mal los datos del json que envio desde mi script.

Ajax:

```
   $.ajax(
{
    url: "http://localhost:54943/ServicioWeb.asmx?op=CancelarReserva",
    data: dataParse,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var resultadoAMostrar = '<p class="alert alert-success">' + response + '</p>';
        $("#error-ajax").html(resultadoAMostrar);
    },
    error: function () {
        var resultadoAMostrar = '<p class="alert alert-danger">ERROR AL CANCELAR LA RESERVA</p>';
        $("#error-ajax").html(resultadoAMostrar);
    }
});
```

Y el metodo de mi webservice es el siguiente:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string CancelarReserva(string ReservaId)
    {

        int ReservaInt = Convert.ToInt32(ReservaId);

        Reserva reservaAEliminar = db.Reserva.Find(ReservaInt);
        Usuario u = reservaAEliminar.Usuario;
        string response = String.Empty;

        if (reservaAEliminar.Paquete.FechaInicio > System.DateTime.Now)
        {

            Paquete paquete = db.Paquete.Where(p => p.Id == reservaAEliminar.IdPaquete).FirstOrDefault();


            paquete.LugaresDisponibles = paquete.LugaresDisponibles + reservaAEliminar.CantPersonas;


            db.Reserva.Remove(reservaAEliminar);

            db.SaveChanges();

            response = "La reserva ha sido cancelada";
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "La fecha de reserva ha expirado";
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
        }



    }
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
POST http://localhost:54943/ServicioWeb.asmx?op=CancelarReserva 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

EDIT: El error me esta devolviendo esta respuesta:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="es">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: El servidor no puede procesar la solicitud. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Los datos del nivel de raíz no son válidos. línea 1, posición 1.
```

Comment: posiblemente es un error en el servidor, agrega un try-catch en tu codigo de C# para que obtengas mas detalles

Comment: El estado 500 indica error del servidor. Algo esta fallando y no fue controlado. Intenta ver el error en la consola

Comment: @Einer efectivamente es un error del servidor, aparentemente no estaria pasando bien los parametros al web service, no es así?

Comment: No hay forma de saber si son los parametros que estan mal a menos que nos muestres el error que lanza.

Comment: @Einer Edite el post con el error que devuelve.

Comment: El método del webservice espera un parámetro no? como se lo envías...revisa este articulo a ver si te aporta información y ya cuentas algo más https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189451/how-can-i-call-a-web-service-and-pass-parameters-using-the-url